# Apache Error Log - an unknown filter was not added: includes

Tags: apache, logging

I'm getting multiple instances of the following error in my Mac OS X Apache error_log:

```
[Thu Jun 25 17:11:56.789373 2015] [core:error] [pid 277] [client 127.0.0.1:58739] AH00082: an unknown filter was not added: includes
```

I've been searching but haven't been able to locate what the cause of this is. Is there a way to get more specific details about what is causing this?

Comment: Related bug report for Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1675184

Answer (score 11):

If you have:

```
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

included in the configuration, typically when you have `mods-enabled/mime.conf`, and have not enabled the [server side includes](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html) module (`modules/mod_include.so`), then any query by anyone of a file with extension `.shtml` (whether it exists or not, and even if the `Includes` option is not enabled) will cause that error message.

If you don't use server side includes, it's better not to enable the module as there's a small potential security risk associated (though you'd still need to enable the `Includes` option for it to be in effect). If you want that (harmless) error to go away, you can comment-out that `AddOutputFilter` line above.

Comment: One thing worth adding is that, at least as of Apache 2.4.18, this error seems to end up in your default error log even if you have a separate error log file for the VirtualHost that triggered it. Since it happens for non-existent files, that makes it really hard to track down. I ended up just searching all my logs for the IP address in the error to make sure it wasn't a real file causing it. Turned out some bot was looking for an `.shtml` file that never existed.

Answer (score 5):

Actually what most likely happened was:

1. You have `SetOutputFilter DEFLATE` in your config
2. You have NOT enabled the `mod_deflate` module

In my particular case, I had to simply uncomment this line:

```
LoadModule deflate_module libexec/apache2/mod_deflate.so
```

and then all was well.

Comment: This probably would be correct if the message said "an unknown filter was not added: deflate" instead of the one in the OP.

Answer (score 3):

I am having troubles with Yosemite and the apache2 settings, but historically this error means you need to (1) allow overrides, in httpd.conf, and perhaps (2) in your .htaccess you say Options +Includes:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_include.html

Answer (score 1):

Looking over this thread, it seems there are quite a few ways that can cause this error. In my case, mod_include was not enabled and in the virtual host directive I had:

```
Options Includes
```

Removing that directive or enabling the module (a2enmod include) fixed.

Answer (score 1):

this error happend to me once.
In my case this error is displayed when the document root is not configured correctly in the ssl.conf file.
Maybe someone will serve this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue today. It turned out the mode include was not enabled. So just issue the two below command and the error should be gone:

```
sudo a2enmod include
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```